# How to create a new MySQL server instance in workbench?

Tags: mysql

I'm using:
Mac OS X
MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.27 
And latest MySQL workbench, which, for some reason, still telling me, that it uses MySQl version 5.6.24.

So, I could create new connections, but when I try to **configure local management**, in stage of **test settings** I always get:

> Error: error calling Python module function
>   WbAdmin.testInstanceSettingByName
>
> Check if /etc/my.cnf can be accessed File was found at the expected
>   location Check if section for instance mysqld exists in /etc/my.cnf
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_grt.py",
>   line 777, in testInstanceSettingByName
>       if check_if_config_file_has_section(open(config_file, "r"), section): IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/my.cnf'
>   Operation failed: error calling Python module function
>   WbAdmin.testInstanceSettingByName

I suppose, that it is caused by absence of any server instances. When I try to **Rescan for Local MySQL Servers**, I get message:

> No servers were found.

So, what's wrong? How to solve this problem, how to create a server instance?

Comment: This may help you http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,543277,543277#msg-543277

Comment: Well, I've already tried that, but it doesn't help. After deleting the my.cnf WB creates new file, that is the same as previous - it's empty.

Comment: What happens when you try to add a connection after that?

Comment: All the same: I could create new connections, but WB can't see any instances, in configure local management it's the same error, as was described in question.

Comment: Is the server running and accessible for you over command line or any other client?

Comment: Now I can't do it. (Message from terminal: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91285/discussion-between-user3289673-and-james-jithin).